# Is it possible to edit surveys using FluidSurveys API?

Tags: json, api, survey, surveymonkey

I want to build custom application using [FluidSuvery APIs](http://docs.fluidsurveys.com/). I had read whole documentation of FluidSurvey API, but not found API call to edit already created survey. By edit survey I mean one should able to edit questions, options associated with questions etc.

Answer (score 1):

- GET /api/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/structure/ will return the entire survey JSON
- PUT /api/v3/surveys/{survey_id}/structure/ with {"structure": value_from_GET} will update

There's no documentation on the JSON structure, and it's not covered by support, but feel free to use the UI and API to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Adam but Not working with v3 api, its returning 403: Forbidden, event though required credentials are correct. Where as when tried with v2 api GET is working put PUT is not working. Currently I am using free account of fluid survey